# React Native FCM token not accepted as device token in amazon SNS

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement amazon SNS in my react native app using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). For this, i have integrated the react-native-firebase library. With this library i can retrieve my FCM receiver ID  which i need to use for SNS to create endpoints. However, when i enter that Registration ID of firebase into Amazon SNS it says that it is not valid due to not being hexadecimal.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the hexadecimal token or how to convert my token to hexadecimal in javascript?

The format of my current Registration ID is

```
dL2CjuuXskpqlcNLoiPqBC:APA91bFgvmNwRFpy4SA0XDtZig4cwFMLDdBy5Ab9-
AW2LKuE0lZW34tyCBgwwnXbUlVyvIsApAODtQnybjQlq2L10oqoDC-wbR160od_j2wJO23yy65NM1-
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks in advance.